# Restart Bound Service after force stopped

Tags: android, service, android-service

I have a bounded service in my application, I am using that service to track location of user. I want to make this service running always, right now if the user killed the service from android app settings, or using any task killer app, the service stops and is not restarting. so I want this service as a high priority one.

`onStartCommand` of service is given below

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        LogUtils.LOGI(TAG, "Service onStartCommand called " + startId);
        startLocationUpdates();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
```

how will be the behaviour if the return value is `super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);`

I have changed return value to `START_STICKY`, but still it is not restating. what change I have to do ?

**EDIT**

I am restarting service from onDestroy() method of service. it works proper. but if I force closed twice immediately then onDestroy of service is not calling. so I cant restart

*check my log :*

```
11-03 10:36:26.455/tag: ACTION_SERVICE_FORCE_CLOSE on receive called
11-03 10:36:26.486/LocationUpdateService: Service created
11-03 10:36:26.486/LocationUpdateService: Building GoogleApiClient
11-03 10:36:26.486/LocationUpdateService: Service onStartCommand called 1
11-03 10:36:26.525/LocationUpdateService: GoogleApiClient callback onConnected called
11-03 10:36:30.134/LocationUpdateService: Service destroyed
11-03 10:36:30.361/tag: ACTION_SERVICE_FORCE_CLOSE on receive called
11-03 10:36:30.369/LocationUpdateService: Service created
11-03 10:36:30.369/LocationUpdateService: Building GoogleApiClient
11-03 10:36:30.376/LocationUpdateService: Service onStartCommand called 1
11-03 10:36:30.415/LocationUpdateService: GoogleApiClient callback onConnected called
```

there it stops. how do i resolve this ?

Comment: have you tried 'START_REDELIVER_INTENT' ?

Comment: Not working with a task killer app or not working with "Force Stop"? Or both? [I'd expect it to work with the task killer, because they are said to work like the system's own "out-of-memory-killer"]

Comment: not working when Force Stopped

Comment: restarts(working fine) if I killed with task killer app

Comment: The difference seems to be that the task killer apps call 'ActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses()', just like the system does when low on RAM. You could use "startForeground()" with the service to be on the safe side there. - The "Force Stop by user " seems to work differently. Very. But then, the user is warned that the app data (and consequently its behavior) may be damaged if an app is force stopped.

Comment: according to [this stackexchange question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19987), it is worth a try to override 'Service.onTaskRemoved()'. Anything with 'Service.onDestroy()' may not work because like with activities, the method is not guaranteed to be called.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94066/discussion-between-0x0nosugar-and-vivid-vervet).

Comment: Can you post onDestroy method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write code in `onDestory()` to start itself.

Good luck there.

Comment: Yep, its dirty way to archive your goal. Another solution is wrting a Braodcast receiver which registered to spesific events. Like BOOT_COMPLETED, But if user kills, there is the only way to override onDestroy as i know.

Comment: there might be some ways, check WhatsApp restarts service when we force stop

Comment: https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/master/TMessagesProj/src/main/java/org/telegram/messenger/NotificationsService.java#L38 This is how telegram forces it.

Comment: Can you please post your onDestory?

Comment: I don't have the code with me now, may be I can post it tomorrow, I am triggering a broadcast from onDestroy. And I've a log in onDestroy, that is not showing in logcat that means Destroy is not getting called.